# State of Eclipse plugin for Gluon-Mobile

Tags: java, eclipse, gluon, gluon-mobile

Can anybody tell me what the state of the Eclipse plugin for Gluon-Mobile is? It cannot be installed from the Eclipse marketplace anymore for the more recent Eclipse versions although the text states that it is compatible with the latest versions. Currently the marketplace is showing more than 80 failed installation attempts within the last 7 days.

Comment: Solution would be to switch to Xamarin with VS

Comment: @A.Sharma I am wondering how Xamarin or VS is going to help me getting my JavaFX codebase running on Android. The obvious solution is to switch to IntelliJ but as long as an Eclipse plugin is offered and advertised I'd prefer that because I am one of these dinosaurs who still believes in Eclipse.

Comment: There was an issue with Buildship, it was [filed](https://github.com/gluonhq/ide-plugins/issues/19) and solved, but it hasn't been published yet. However, you might want to [try the fix](https://github.com/gluonhq/ide-plugins/issues/19#issuecomment-459901243)?

Comment: Installation of the fix on Eclipse19-3 went smoothly. I'll give it a try when I have my new Tablet :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Gluon plugin for Eclipse works with Eclipse Version: 2019-03 (4.11.0) with the fix:

https://github.com/gluonhq/ide-plugins/issues/19

I tested it:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yBg43PJ-Sx4

Comment: ... and also with Eclipse 2020-06 (and Java(FX)8!) as I just checked.